# Android app not pulling info from sharedpreferences activity. Using default

Tags: android

I have finished making an app. But I have some text in a sharedpreferences activity, and when the app starts it should pull it from there and insert it into an edittext, but if the app is fully closed, or the phone rebooted it doesn't work and the default value is used instead.

Could anyone tell me why this is? And what data you would need.

Below is the main activity.

```
package com.liamwli.smsbusy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Sms_busyActivity extends Activity {
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    ToggleButton endis;
    EditText message;
    Button smessage;
    SharedPreferences getPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Intent i = new Intent("com.liamwli.smsbusy.PREFS");
        // startActivity(i);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        endis = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.enableddis);

        smessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savemess);

        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        editor = getPrefs.edit();

        // ---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        Boolean state = getPrefs.getBoolean("enabled", false);

        String stext = getPrefs.getString("text", "");

        message.setText(stext);

        if (message.getText().toString().contentEquals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to get saved message. Please resave.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        endis.setChecked(state);

        endis.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onCheckedChanged Called");

                //Toast.makeText(Sms_busyActivity.this, "App state changed",
                        //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (endis.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("enabled", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }else {
                    editor.putBoolean("enabled", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }

                editor.putString("message", message.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();

            }
        });

        smessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                editor.putString("message", message.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(Sms_busyActivity.this, "Message Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("smessage", "Message saved & commited");

            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("SMS Busy App", "onBackPressed Called");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

Comment: We'd need to see the code you are using to load the preferences and save the changed values.

Comment: It's all done in the main activity. OP updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `Editor` for every call, and `commit`ting it more than once. This will only save the most recent change throughout the entire application.

Try this:

```
            editor = getPrefs.edit();
            if (endis.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("enabled", true);
            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("enabled", false);
            }
            editor.putString("message", message.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

And adjust your other `commit` code in the same manner.

Comment: Still doesn't recall it after a reboot :( It's strange, because the toggle button state is recalled and set....

Comment: Phone reboot & app reboot. If the app is fully closed, it won't recall.

Comment: Try [this code](http://pastebin.com/2HsK9i5h). I just ran it in the `onCreate` of an app of my own, and it worked as expected--`false` on the first run, `true` on every run after that (including after phone reboot).

Comment: Ok, fixed it. I'm the biggest idiot in the world. I was putting the string into the wrong key! I'm an idiot.

Comment: Heh, guess I should have noticed that, too. Glad you got it fixed. :)